# print only text discarding text properties

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have the following function to print the line where point is to the *scratch* buffer,

```
(defun print-line ()
  (print (thing-at-point 'line) (get-buffer "*scratch*")))
```

but it prints even the fontified info like this

```
#(" OFFICE
" 0 2 (fontified t org ...
```

How to discard the printing of the fontified info.

Comment: substring-no-properties is like substring but discards text properties, so given some string `line` that contains text properties, one can just use `(substring-no-properties line)` to obtain just the contents of the string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I needed something similar for [eredis](http://code.google.com/p/eredis/) when manipulating strings from an org-table. You can use [`set-text-properties'](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Changing-Properties.html) to get rid of them when displaying the string.

```
(defun strip-text-properties(txt)
  (set-text-properties 0 (length txt) nil txt)
      txt)

(defun print-line ()
 (print (strip-text-properties 
         (thing-at-point 'line))
    (get-buffer "*scratch*")))
```

Answer (score 19):

To expand on Daimrod's mention of `buffer-substring-no-properties`...

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `apropos` <kbd>RET</kbd> `no-properties` <kbd>RET</kbd>

```
buffer-substring-no-properties
  Function: Return the characters of part of the buffer, without the
            text properties.
field-string-no-properties
  Function: Return the contents of the field around POS, without text
            properties.
insert-buffer-substring-no-properties
  Function: Insert before point a substring of BUFFER, without text
            properties.
match-string-no-properties
  Function: Return string of text matched by last search, without text
            properties.
minibuffer-contents-no-properties
  Function: Return the user input in a minibuffer as a string, without
            text-properties.
substring-no-properties
  Function: Return a substring of STRING, without text properties.
```

You can read about text properties in the manual:

<kbd>M-:</kbd> (info "(elisp) Text Properties") <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: Woa I didn't notice `substring-no-properties`, but with it one can just do `(defun print-line () (let ((line (thing-at-point 'line))) (substring-no-properties line 0 (length line))))`.

Comment: @Daimrod The arguments of `substring-no-properties` are optional.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried some things but it's weird, I don't really understand how text properties work.

For example:

```
(type-of (thing-at-point 'line)) => string
```

As you've said if one tries to print it, the properties are printed as well, but if one tries to insert it:

```
(insert (format "%s" (thing-at-point 'line)))
```

Only the string is printed, not the properties.

So it seems to me that those properties are just bound to the string but you can manipulate the string as usual:

```
(lenght (thing-at-point 'line))
(substring (thing-at-point 'line) 0 2)
```

However, if all you want is the line, and the line only you can use `buffer-substring-no-properties`:

```
(defun print-line ()     
  (print (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-at-bol) (point-at-eol))))
```

Comment: Even buffer-string prints the fontified messages, buffer-substring-no-properties  prints without fontified messages.